# Run multiple processes (multiple watch commands)

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to make a Makefile that executes multiple commands. Example:

```
script:
  cat scripts/*.js > public/scripts/scripts.js

vendor:
  cat vendor/*.js > public/scripts/vendor.js

watchStyles:
  stylus -w -u nib styles/styles.styl -o public/styles

watchScripts:
  watchr -e "watch('scripts/.*\.js') {system 'make scripts'}"

watchVendor:
  watchr -e "watch('vendor/.*\.js') {system 'make vendor'}"
```

Right now I have to open up 3 terminals, which is annoying. How can I run only one via `make watch`?

```
watch: watchStyles watchScripts watchVendor
```

Comment: So, what exactly is it that `make watch` (or, equivalently, `make watchStyles watchScripts watchVendor`) doesn't do?

Comment: it only runs the first process, and not the other two.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: What version of Make? (You can find out with `make -v`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using GNU make then [`-j` option allows it to build targets in parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel), e.g.:

```
make -j4 watchStyles watchScripts watchVendor
```

Comment: hah, this is exactly what i want! is there a way to make this a make command? ie, i only want to type `make watch`.

Comment: `watch:\n 
 make  -j4 watchStyles watchScripts watchVendor` would you say this works fine?

Comment: Create a target `watch` as in the end of your original post. And then `make -j4 watch`.

Comment: @JonathanOng: `watch: ; ${MAKE} -j4 watchStyles watchScripts watchVendor` would do the trick.

Comment: Works like a charm. What does the `; ${MAKE}` part do?

Comment: It's a way to put the first line of a recipe in the same line with the rule: ['... except that the first recipe line may be attached to the target-and-prerequisites line with a semicolon in between'](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recipe-Syntax).

Comment: And `${MAKE}` is the name of the running make binary, in case there are more than one version.